# Wget download many files in the sublink of a webpage

Tags: download, wget, subdirectory

I am trying to download many files (~30,000) using wget, all files are in the following webpage:

```
http://galex.stsci.edu/gr6/?page=tilelist&survey=ais&showall=Y
```

However, the real data is under a sublink after I click `Fits` and then some file under this sublink is displayed. For example, the sublink of the first file is the following:

```
http://galex.stsci.edu/gr6/?page=downloadlist&tilenum=50270&type=coaddI&subvis=28&img=1
```

I only want to download one file in this sublink: `Intensity Map` of band `NUV`. In this above case, it is the second file that I want to download.

All files have the same structure. How could I use wget to download all the files under sublink?

Answer (score 1):

The **Intensity Map** of band **NUV** files have a common ending, which should allow you to download only the files you want using `wget -r -A "*nd-int.fits.gz"` on the target site. This employs wget's recursive function, `-r`, and the Accept List function, `-A`. The Accept List function, outlined [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Types-of-Files.html), will only download the files you want according to extension, name, or naming convention. Whether the wget recursive function can successfully crawl the entirety of your target site is something you'll have to test.

If the above doesn't work, the website seems to have handy tools for filtering available files, such as a [catalog search](http://galex.stsci.edu/gr6/?page=mastform).

Comment: Thanks Tigelle. I tried your method `wget -r -A "*nd-int.fits.gz" http://galex.stsci.edu/gr6/?page=tilelist&survey=ais&showall=Y`, but it did not work. The catalog search will returns the objects in the images, however, I want to measure some objects in the images by myself. So I want to download those images.

Comment: The sublink is not a subfolder, so that is probably the reason why it is not working.

Comment: @Huanian Zhang you might try that wget command on  "http://galex.stsci.edu/gr6/" or even "http://galex.stsci.edu/." I'm not sure of this, but I assume you're restricting wget by using the full url you listed above.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but there is no matched item in this url. I will try other things.

Comment: Did you try the base url without `/gr6/`? I see that the url for one target file is `http://galex.stsci.edu/data/GR6/pipe/02-vsn/50270-AIS_270/d/01-main/0001-img/07-try/AIS_270_sg28-nd-int.fits.gz`, so maybe you should target `http://galex.stsci.edu/` or `http://galex.stsci.edu/data/GR6/pipe/` if you haven't already.

Comment: Yes, I tried the case url without /gr6/, it only downloads a very small portion of the data. It is indeed in the directory `/data/GR6/pipe`. Thank you very much for all the help.

Comment: I contact the Galex science team. They provide me the link to all the files I want in a text file. Then I can use it to download all images I want. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Excellent. Glad to hear it.